# Asp.net Stress Testing - where is the missing time?

Tags: asp.net, stress-testing

There are huge differences from the result on the Stress Testing tool (WebLoad) and Timers in Code 
Behind,

Where is the missing time?

Network Latency? (Not a heavy Load: Max Load Size 80 for 17 Min, no other traffic)

IIS?

How can I measure the gaps?

**Results for one page ("Landing"):**

WebLoad Avg Result = **3.1 Sec** - WebLoad timer "Landing"

Code Behind = **0.05 Sec** - Begin Request -> End Request.

A simple browser Request = **0.5 Sec**

**Code Behind:**

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stopwatch RequestTimer = new Stopwatch();
        RequestTimer.Start();

        HttpContext.Current.Items["RequestTimer"] = RequestTimer;
    }

    protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Items["RequestTimer"] != null)
        {
            Stopwatch RequestTimer = (Stopwatch)HttpContext.Current.Items["RequestTimer"];
            RequestTimer.Stop();
            Logger.SectionEnd("RequestTimer", RequestTimer, "", true); //Per Page Name
        }
    }
```

**A Part of the WebLoad Code:**

```
 wlGlobals.GetFrames = false 
wlHttp.Header["Host"] = host
wlHttp.Header["Proxy-Connection"] = "off"
wlHttp.Header["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.77 Safari/535.7"
wlHttp.Header["Accept"] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,\x2A/\x2A;q=0.8"
//wlHttp.Header["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip,deflate,sdch"
wlHttp.Header["Accept-Language"] = "en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6"
wlHttp.Header["Accept-Charset"] = "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3"
SetTimer ("Landing")
wlHttp.Get(url)
SendTimer ("Landing")
```

Running on .Net 4 IIS7.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the code timer and the load time observed in the browser is mostly the network time and the page rendering time.  Since WebLoad does not render the page (IIRC), then it will not include that component - only the network time. The large difference between the browser time and WebLoad time is a bit concerning. Does WebLoad properly simulate multiple connections?  Modern browsers use a lot more connections (6-8 per host) to load a page than older browsers did. When latency is high, this can greatly improve load times.  If WebLoad is only using 2 connections/host (which is what most browsers did prior to ~2009), then it could skew the measurement considerably.

Comment: When running the test I made a request with a browser and got similar results. I think most of the latency is in the IIS level, can I measure it?